# nginx proxy from https to http getting Blocked loading mixed active content error

Tags: jquery, http, https

I am working with nginx (openresty) and am trying to setup a proxy from the public wan using https to an apache server on a private 10 network using http.  The application that I am trying to proxy is openscrum.  The page loads but some of the javascript (jquery and more) is trying to come over http and not https.  Using firebug I see these errors:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://privateurl.com/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"
```

I cannot figure out what the solution is, here is what I am using for the nginx virtual host:

```
upstream SVRLINK {
  server    10.100.200.25;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name   mgt.privateurl.com.com;
  rewrite       ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
  listen        443 ssl;
  server_name   mgt.privateurl.com.com;

  ssl                   on;
  ssl_certificate         /opt/services/configs/mgt/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /opt/services/configs/mgt/key.pem;
  ssl_client_certificate  /opt/services/certs/public_certs/mychain.pem;
  ssl_verify_depth 5;
  # ssl_verify_client on;

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers           ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;
  client_max_body_size 20m;
  error_log   /etc/openresty/nginx/logs/error debug;
  access_log /etc/openresty/nginx/logs/access;

  location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   # proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://SVRLINK;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get this working?  Thank you for taking the time.

-stabiuti

Answer (score 1):

This most likely has nothing to do with your nginx, and far more to do with the web application's html.

If they have hard coded http into the script and css tags, then you will often see these issues.  Check the frontend templates and there are nice tricks like using protocol short urls (https://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/)

Like this   which will let the browser use either https or http depending on how the page was served.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I thought that I had replied to this entry.  I took what you said and forced a rewrite in the nginx code.  Again sorry for the response delay.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped.

Comment: Nick it did, you pointed me in the direction that I needed to look into.  Most of the time a direction of attack is all that is needed.  Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late by almost half a decade, but I faced the issue recently and for me the solution was setting in HTML page:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Setting the following in nginx:

```
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://your_server_host:your_server_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the following line of code in the beginning of Apache's site configuration file (outside of "VirtualHost" block):

`SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on`

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170626220148/http://blog.ajnicholls.com/varnish-apache-and-https/)